# Reporting errors in launching rails webrick server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, webrick, radrails

I have an application which runs on rails 2.3.2 and now i upgraded my version of rails to 3.0.3

After i try to start the application server by typing `rails server`

I get a list of arguments that i should pass to the command. This suggests the server did not start successfully. However, where can i get a list of the errors encountered in starting rails server ?

Also, i am using RVM for managing rails versions. However, even after changing the current running version of rails, radrails is still using the old version of rails. How can i instruct radrails to use the current system rails version ?

```
---> rails server
      exists  
      exists  app/controllers
      exists  app/helpers
      exists  app/models
      exists  app/views/layouts
      exists  config/environments
      exists  config/initializers
      exists  config/locales
      exists  db
      exists  doc
      exists  lib
      exists  lib/tasks
      exists  log
      exists  public/images
      exists  public/javascripts
      exists  public/stylesheets
      exists  script/performance
      exists  test/fixtures
      exists  test/functional
      exists  test/integration
      exists  test/performance
      exists  test/unit
      exists  vendor
      exists  vendor/plugins
      exists  tmp/sessions
      exists  tmp/sockets
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
```

Comment: Are you in the application's root directory when executing `rails server`? Also, you can have RVM change the system ruby version to the most recent one, which will make all applications use that version.

Comment: errors posted in my original post.

Comment: with most rails commands you can give it "--trace" as an argument to get the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not errors, it's the output of the "rails" command from rails 2.3.x

You created a new rails project called server in the directory where u ran the command.

Check the gemset on rvm and see if you're using the correct rails version and check the `config/environment.rb` in your application and see if your application is using rails 3.

You can see it in `RAILS_GEM_VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

The output you're seeing suggests that the rails binary you're executing is for 2.3.x, not rails 3.0.0. Try `rails --version`. My guess is that you just need to run `gem install rails`.