# Rails web server isn't starting up (but it did before I lost power)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I'm having a strange problem where my rails web server (webrick) won't start.  Everything was working fine but then my mac (OS 10.8) went to sleep from lack of power. (I'm more familiar with windows so I'm not sure if it was sleep or hibernate or what the technical state was, but basically the battery got too low.)

I plugged it in and got the mac turned on again, but now `rails s` gives me the following output:

```
rails s
  exists  
  exists  app/controllers
  exists  app/helpers
  exists  app/models
  exists  app/views/layouts
  exists  config/environments
  exists  config/initializers
  exists  config/locales
  exists  db
  exists  doc
  exists  lib
  exists  lib/tasks
  exists  log
  exists  public/images
  exists  public/javascripts
  exists  public/stylesheets
  exists  script/performance
  exists  test/fixtures
  exists  test/functional
  exists  test/integration
  exists  test/performance
  exists  test/unit
  exists  vendor
  exists  vendor/plugins
  exists  tmp/sessions
  exists  tmp/sockets
  exists  tmp/cache
  exists  tmp/pids
identical  Rakefile
identical  README
identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
identical  config/database.yml
identical  config/routes.rb
identical  config/locales/en.yml
identical  db/seeds.rb
identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] q
aborting app
```

I looked at the threads at [Reporting errors in launching rails webrick server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367710/reporting-errors-in-launching-rails-webrick-server) and [rails script/server doesn't start the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949855/rails-script-server-doesnt-start-the-server) but it seems to be a different issue since I had everything installed and working prior.

Again, it was running fine until my battery ran low and it powered off.

I also tried creating a brand new rails project and did nothing more than the initial `rails dummy` to create a dummy project.  When I run `rails s` in the project and select the diff option I get the following output:

```
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] d
--- s/config/initializers/session_store.rb  2012-07-30 19:36:06.000000000 -0400
+++ s/config/initializers/session_store.rb20120730-26164-2nbrgz-0   2012-07-30 19:36:28.000000000 -0400
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@
 # no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
 ActionController::Base.session = {
   :key         => '_s_session',
-  :secret      => '0de919861d30e11a894d96d395ec2340fd40d88309035bea3033bbf2a6f3c3e0b3a42afa9ec208533547e025be363c19439d79b22ed5b04709442e9d50dcf985'
+  :secret      => '2609e7c27f761383e77cda8b7a7dead04ffa6ad47ce3bd540f946a1fcdfe9dec9a87cc71880e50db9f94d68afe5c4bce9efb621024a9ce69a7af22b44a266a43'
 }

 # Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I'm lost.

Comment: which version of rails are you using ? can you paste the output of rails --version pls ? It seems that you're using a version prior to 3.x for versions lower you should use rails server since rails s is generating a new app named s in the directory s

Comment: Apparently Rails was treating "s" or "server" as a project name and not a reserved word, so I was generating a new project inside my existing project.  I have no idea why.  Note: to your point it gave me the same problem with "rails server" as "rails s", it created a new project called rails.

I did explicitly force rvm back to an older version of ruby (1.9.2 from 1.9.3) and that worked.  I'm not sure how the rails version changed.  I'm 100% sure I didn't change it (I haven't done so in months).  I can only assume there was a non-atomic operation that happened as I lost power.